# Sharepoint 2013 Online CORS Cross Origin Resource Sharing

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to implement a simple Sharepoint 2013 Online solution to allow sharepoint to visualize an externale source inside an Iframe, the external source in this case is OWA. Placing a simple page visualizer it doesn't work because SHAREPOINT doesn't allow it becuse it sets X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN. So I'm trying to bypass it via a simple Javascript to change the HttpHeader sent to the server. This is my code so far:

```
<HTML>
<head>
 <script>
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("get", "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dw-local/luca-pappallardo/SitePages/OWAgsfn.aspx", true);
 xhr.onload = function(){
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FRAME-OPTION", "ALLOWALL");
};
xhr.send(null);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

But I still got an error, in the specific case that one below:

> Refused to display
>   'https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?exsvurl=1&realm=office365.com&Silent=1'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Does anyone know why and where I'm getting wrong? I know that this can be done, but I don't know where I'm getting wrong. Please can anyone help me out or can correct my above script? Thanks very much in advance.